# What method do i have to use in counting the no. of males and females in the dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc

So i am working with an RDLC report and what i want is to count how many males and females are there in a company.

[image]

Here is my code for getting distinct value of companies

```
            ReportsData m = new ReportsData();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM TBL_Users WHERE Course = '" + cmbCourse.Text + "' ", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(m, m.Tables[0].TableName);
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("CompData", m.Tables[0]);
            this.rpvSL.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.rpvSL.RefreshReport();

            ReportsData ma = new ReportsData();
            SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TBL_Users WHERE Course = '" + cmbCourse.Text + "'  ", con);
            daa.Fill(ma, ma.Tables[0].TableName);
            ReportDataSource rdsa = new ReportDataSource("StudentData", ma.Tables[0]);
            this.rpvSL.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.rpvSL.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            this.rpvSL.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsa);
            this.rpvSL.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.rpvSL.RefreshReport();
```

As you can see i am listing a distinct list of companies and want to count how many males and females are there in a specific company.

Comment: The easiest way is to use linq on the DataTable : ma.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { and then your query here })

Comment: Sorry for asking but can you reconstruct the code for me i am new to that kind of method good sir

Comment: I do not know the column names in TBL_Users

Comment: Company, FullName, Gender are examples of columns in my table

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Company"))
                .Select(x => new { company = x.Key, employes = x.Count(), male = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Gender") == "M").Count(), female = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Gender") == "F").Count() })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: daa.Fill(ma, ma.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {"SELECT * FROM TBL_Users WHERE Course = '" + cmbCourse.Text + "'  ", con}); there seems to be a problem here ?

Comment: Do not make one instruction.  Do it in pieces so it is easier to find the errors.